# scroll view & flat list scroll is not working when parent container have position absolute in react native(android)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

here is my code: Basically I want to render the list in absolute view but it's not working in android,
when I tested this code on IOS it works fine

```
<View
    style={[
        styles.shadow,
        {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 47,
            width: '95%',
            borderBottomRightRadius: 15,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 15,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            zIndex: 1,
            maxHeight: metrics.height * 0.35,
            ...dropdownStyle
        },
    ]}>
    <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 9000 }}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        keyExtractor={item => item.filter_id}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return <Tc key={index}
                onPress={() => onPress(item)}
                style={{
                zIndex: 100,
                borderTopWidth: index == 0 ? 0 : 0.5,
                borderTopColor: colors.grey,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                paddingHorizontal: 10,
                paddingVertical: 15,}}>
                <Text
                   style={{textTransform:'capitalize'}}
                   testID={'searchDropdownOption'}
                   accessibilityLabel={'searchDropdownOption'}>
                   {item.filter_name}
                </Text>
              </Tc>
</View>
```

this above code is the view I have render in my screen.